# Scroll not working in iphone using iframe. Is there any way to dynamically load htmls into a another html without using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scorm

I am adding some html's dynamically using an iframe src. I have designed these htmls in responsivve mode. But i am getting the problem regarding the scroll using iframe in Iphone. Is ther any other way to dynamicaly load html pages so that it can be useful to my requirement.

Comment: I am adding some html pages into an array and passing the array to the iframe source. as
 theIframe.src = "../" + pageArray[currentPage].pageName;

Is there any other way to add this array of htmls dynamically without iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off fixing the scrolling via JavaScript. There are a bunch of tutorials explaining how. Here's a recent one: http://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at jquery's [.load();](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?